MSAccess unexpectedly change the character i to I in my code
I paste the following code to a text or memo field in msaccess table
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var thisCell = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
  var thisContent; 
  thisContent = 1000 + i + '. ' + thisCell.textContent;
  thisCell.textContent = thisContent;
  

but find that it becomes after leaving the field:
for (var I = 1; I < rows.length; i++) {
  var thisCell = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
  var thisContent; 
  thisContent = 1000 + I + '. ' + thisCell.textContent;
  thisCell.textContent = thisContent;

so my codes cannot be run later without fixing it firstly.
What is wrong?

Please provide a [mre], are you doing this in table view or somewhere else? If you have autocorrect enabled on a text field, it's usual that i gets capitalized.

Yes, I do that in the table view.
I find the spelling check option that apply to the whole database. I don't seem to have this problem before. Thank for your solution.

I might be totally off base here but replace "var" with "dim". In VBA you will dim variables rather than var them. Unless this code is to be run outside of the VBA instance.
